# AUTOSAR Inter runnable variables

Tags: autosar

Is there is a way to filter Autosar IRV like in S/R non-queued data reception?

I want to receive the IRV only at specific times for each runnable.

Comment: This question needs more generalist language, details, and probably additional tagging.

Answer (score 1):

No, that‘s not supported. But frankly, I don’t understand the use case.

If you want to receive the InterrunnableVariable only at specific times then simply make sure to send it only at specific times.

After all, if you are authoring the enclosing software-component then you have full control over the behavior of the InterrunableVariable and the RunnableEntities that send or receive it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I want to use implicit inter runnable variables but i want them to be sent once every N cycle to certain runnables and every M cycles to other runnables. This i can do with implicit receive mode in sender receiver interface and i was wondering whether this is possible with implicit IRVs or not directly from the component configurations without a manually written code inside the runnable with explicit IRVs